# Backup Apps Without Backing Up Rom

Tags: cyanogenmod

After doing something wrong while installing CyanogenMod 13, I flashed a google marshmallow stock rom. I wanted to go back to CyanogenMod 12, so I backed up my data using CWM recovery, factory reset, and installed CM12. After making sure it was working, I flashed Gapps and restored from my recovery. My apps were back, but I was also back with the google stock rom. Is there any way to only back up the app data?

Comment: You can use [ADB to backup app data](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28296/full-backup-of-non-rooted-devices). You can use [Titanium Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup&hl=en) app to backup app data. While not personally tested, [Adebar](https://github.com/IzzySoft/Adebar) should help you as well. Or, if you're familiar with *nix command line, make a list of package name of apps whose data you want, boot into recovery, mount data partition and selectively copy or zip the `/data/data/` directories of all the apps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments by Firelord and me, there are multiple approaches:

- you could use [Titanium Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup)
- you could use [ES File Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop), which includes an app manager capable of backing up apps and their data
- you could use [ADB backup](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/28296/16575)
- You could use [Adebar](https://github.com/IzzySoft/Adebar) to make the previous step easier

*TiBu* and *ES File Manager* require root to work. ADB and *Adebar* don't.

*Adebar* a.o. creates a script to backup each of your (user) apps into a separate archive using `adb backup` (and another one for the data of system apps, and two others for restore). While you could do a similar thing with TiBu (which uses its own backup format), *Adebar* runs from the command line while with TiBu you must use a GUI. Side effect from using *Adebar:* you'll have your device documented: tech specs, apps installed, etc :)

*Adebar* is pretty easy to install, but will require [adb](/questions/tagged/adb) to be available on your computer (see our [adb tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/adb/info) for details on that). It runs fine on Linux, and recently was reported to run on Windows as well via Cygwin.

Disclaimer: I'm the dev of *Adebar.*

Comment: Ok, i used adb backup because i just wanted it to work quickly, but i might take a look at Adebar later

Comment: Anytime! Always glad to help. If you've got any issues with *Adebar*, you know where to find me :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Titanium Backup Pro to backup the apk file as well as data of your apps.Otherwise, if you want to backup just the apk files, you can use App Backup Restore.You can also copy the apk files from \data\app to your SD card via a suitable file explorer like Root Explorer or ES File Explorer.